# SQL sum statement invaild identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column of total quantity in each order using query

```
update orders 
set total_items = (SELECT L_QUANTITY AS "TOTAL" 
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT o_orderkey, SUM(L_Quantity) AS "TOTAL" 
                        FROM LINEITEM L 
                        JOIN ORDERS O ON O.O_ORDERKEY = L.L_orderkey 
                        WHERE L.L_orderkey > 1 
                        GROUP BY o_orderkey));
```

Oracle shows this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "L_QUANTITY": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: orcale sql, sorry i got confused.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you describe, you just need a correlated subquery:

```
update orders o
    set total_items = (SELECT SUM(L_Quantity)
                       FROM LINEITEM L
                       WHERE O.O_ORDERKEY = L.L_orderkey AND L.L_orderkey > 1 
                      );
```

I'm not sure what the condition on `L.L_Orderkey` is supposed to be doing.

Your particular problem is because the innermost subquery has no column called `L_QUANTITY` (the sum is called `TOTAL`).  But, if you fixed that, you would just have other problems, such as a scalar subquery returning too many rows.